# how to integrate Falgun theme into Rails application?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, themes

My client wants me to use this theme:

http://themeforest.net/item/falgun-metro-style-bootstrap-admin-dashboard/4257951

How am supposed to do it? I cant find any tutorials about using custom themes in general.

Comment: Above mentioned Falgun theme is only a bunch of CSS files on top of Twitter Bootstrap. Copying only needed files to vendor/assets and adding path to those assets in JavaScript and CSS manifest files did the trick. The problem was that at my first attempt I have copied everything. Adding twitter-bootstrap-rails gem and reading about Twitter Bootstrap in general helped me to make some progress.

Comment: background-image:url("../images/crop.gif") doesn't work, you have to edit CSS files to look like this:

Comment: background-image:url("crop.gif")